# French or Belgian comic book from the 1960s or 1970s. A group of teenagers fight against a snake-man with magical powers

Tags: story-identification, comics

The art style had a ["ligne clare" realistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligne_claire) style, Franco-Belgian, similar to [Jacques Martin's Alix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Alix). The story was set in the Arabian or Sahara desert. One of the boys was blond and fair-skinned. The other two were brown skinned and looked Arabian or Indian. One of them was a girl.

The antagonist was a snake man with a cobra head and magical or telepathic powers. In the final moments of the adventure, the blond boy, the Arab girl, and a wise old man flee aboard an improvised raft through an underground river and discover that they are going to fall through a very high waterfall. The wise old man takes all their clothes off and, with the fabric and the sticks from the raft, makes a parachute in a hurry.

I remember very well the images of the naked girl in those last pages. I was very impressed, I didn't know why.

It was in a Spanish magazine published by Bruguera, maybe Mortadelo or Zipi y Zape. It was part of a series, from the 1960s/70s, and was Franco-Belgian.

Comment: _"I remember very well the images of the naked girl in those last pages. I was very impressed, I didn't know why."_ hmmm... Hormones? :)

Comment: Is it something you read in a paperback, or in one of the _Cœurs Vaillants/Tintin_-like magazines? What language was it in? Did it look like it was part of a series or was it a one-time thing? How many pages, approximately?

Comment: @Jenayah I read it in a Spaniard comic magazine, from the Bruguera publishing house. It could have been "Mortadelo" or "Zipi y Zape". But I am almost certain that it was a comic of French or Belgian origin.  It was published in instalments and I couldn't read all of them.

Comment: @Jenayah But it is quite possible that it had the typical characteristics of all these stories influenced by Tintin, about 48 or 50 pages. And clearly looked like a part of a series, like "Alix".

Comment: Oh dear, I remember this scene, this story was serialised in the Sjors or Eppo in the Nertherlands. AFAIR the name of the story was the name of the protagonist, the blond guy. Must think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is from the French/Belgian series **[Corentin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corentin_(comics))** by Paul Cuvelier. I recognized the series from your description and found the volume with the snake-man, *Le Signe de Cobra*. The scene with the parachute and the naked girl is however from another volume, *Le Royaume des Eaux Noires* (see page at bottom).

You can [read the first 8 volumes online](https://archive.org/details/Corentin/page/n1). *Le Signe du Cobra* is #4, and *Le Royaume des Eaux Noires* is #7.

[image]

[image]

[image]